# how does GC behave when a pointer to struct is replaced

Tags: go, garbage-collection

I'm learning Go and I'm reading examples from libraries. I found that some examples are using:

```
type MyType struct {
  Code string
  //...
}


func main() {
  myType := &MyType{...}
  //...
  myType = &MyType{...}
}
```

Basically they are reusing variables. I understand that `&MyType{..}` returns a pointer, later I can replace that pointer. What happens with the previous pointed memory. Will the GC reclaim that memory or will I waste that memory. Maybe this is a silly question and I'm concerned for nothing but I'm trying to learn Go to build performance APIs :)

Comment: That's what garbage collection does. If you can't reference the memory, it can be reclaimed by the GC.

Comment: It might be useful to read up on some stuff in the [runtime](https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/) if you're interested in this (the `GODEBUG` environmental variable as well can be helpful). `pprof` is also really useful.

Answer (score 0):

The memory will be reclaimed by the garbage collector.

If you want to replace the struct you can do it this way:

```
func main() {
    myType := &MyType{...}
    //...
    *myType = MyType{...}
}
```

The difference will probably be negligible though.